# Install Error Magento2

Tags: magento2, php, uninstall-module

I try to install Magento2 in My local system but I got **PHP Extension intl error**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using Ubuntu Linux system and PHP version is 7.x.

Open the terminal application and run the following command:

> apt-get install php-intl

from the user having root privilege.

Restart the apache server and recheck.

Please let me know if you still face the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

@Randhir check that you have intl installed/enable `php -m` in command line